# Nicest way to check if key in object exists and either set the value or null?

Tags: javascript

I seem to be using the check `let title = options.title ? options.title : null;` and wondering if there is a nicer maybe minmized version of doing this? I remember seeing an ES6 version but I just can't remember what it is.

**JS**

```
this.options = options;
this.model = new Model({
        title: this.options.title ? this.options.title : null,
        message: this.options.message ? this.options.message : null,
        list: this.options.list ? this.options.list : null,
        errors: this.options.errors ? this.options.errors : null,
        innerHTML: this.options.html ? this.options.html : null
    });
```

Comment: No reason, I've added null in there but undefined would make more sense!

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way, you can check both your options value and the property. You have full coverage this way so the js interpreter won't throw a nasty error.

```
title: ((this.options && this.options.title) || "defaultValue")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
options.hasOwnProperty('title');
```

Return boolean(true or false)

Or you can use

```
title=options.title || null
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe because this doesn't show how to use it in an object literal, as in the question.

Comment: The second one is very usefull.

Comment: The downvote may have been before you added it in the edit. But it's also not object syntax, it should be `title: options.title || null`

Comment: Yes. But I just meant to provide the logic only.